# PGAdmin create ERD from explicitly selected tables?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, erd

I have the ability to generate an ERD from an entire DB. My DB is huge and I want to focus on a subset of table relationships. Is this supported in PGAdmin?

Comment: Your second question is off-topic here and better suited for [softwarerecs.SE]

Comment: I have used [sql workbench/j](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/) in the past. In particular [DDL](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/script-generation.html#command-genscript).

Comment: You could use [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) with the `--table` filter option and `--schema-only` to export the database schema, then restore it into a temporary database, and create your ER diagram from that.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, that's a good rec.

Comment: Oof, dropping to pg_dump and creating a new temporary database is awfully hacky for wanting to view a subset of tables in an ERD.   Are we sure there's not a baked in way to see only a subset of tables?

Comment: @alfreema https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/erd_tool.html doesn't suggest anything (but doesn't detail the steps for importing an existing database either)

Answer (score 3):

pgAdmin 4 allows you to create an ERD for a specific table.  Doing so brings in all of the table's relationships into the diagram as well.  So if you have a foreign key relationship between the chosen table and another table, it will be shown.

Simply right-click on the table you are interested in, and you will be presented with the following menu, from which you would select "ERD For Table", as shown:

[image]

Comment: `Doing so brings in all of the table's relationships into the diagram as well.` And that's the problem, it seems to work recursively for all relationsships of all tables. Makes the feature almost useless for large databases as well.